# PHP cURL cookies & keeping session open

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm having some trouble with cURL (using PHP). Bascially I want to login and perform some functions on a website. This would usually be fine, however the website generates a unique URL for the login page AND a dynamic/unique POST url each time the login page is accessed that must be used during that session.

Therefore - I am currently navigating to the login page, then scraping the page to retrieve the unique POST url (I'm successful doing that) and then formulating a POST request and dispatching that to the unique URL. It's not working though and I think the problem is either to do with cookies or the fact I'm not keeping the session open...

Firstly, I don't know why cookies aren't being saved (however they are only for that browser session, maybe that could be the reason?).. I've created a test page which stores a cookie and that works.. so maybe it's not my problem.

Secondly, I don't think I'm keeping the session open. I'm calling:

`$curl = curl_init();` then grabbing the unique POST url, then calling `$ch = curl_init($loginPostUrl);` to initialise my POST request and finally after it's all complete

```
curl_close($ch);
curl_close($curl);
```

However, I don't think this is keeping the initial session open whilst making post request (therefore the POST url I retrieved is invalid..)

Could someone please explain how to do these requests in the same session?

Sorry - my explanation is poor, I'll try and clarify if people don't understand.

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If you use cURL to access the page, cookies won't be stored in your browser.
This is is normal : the script is performing the request server-side and this has nothing to do with the way your browser handles cookies.

To achieve what you want, you can use cURL’s ability to save cookies in a file that you can later send along with your requests.
To create or use this file, do : `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar);` (where `$cookieJar` is the path of the file in which you want to save cookies).

And to send the cookies along with your request, do :

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieJar);
```

I hope this answered your question.